# Do older versions of iMacros have "file access extension" to use .CSV?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, imacros

I am learning about iMacros and I would like to try a program that I am developing from the chrome or firefox extension and I need to obtain variables from the .csv file

For what I read I need a license but it is very expensive for me now and I am just starting to program, how can I use the .csv file without a license?

An old version contains access to the .csv?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yep...! (Is the Answer to your Qt...) - All Info on the iMacros Forum and in the Wiki, with all Download Links... - I don't know why you ask that kind of Qt's on this Forum btw, there is not much "Expertise" about iMacros...

Comment: + For those interested, parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30576 (With much more Info and Links... (And a "Free Rant" about buggy SOF, ah-ah...!))